# the process cannot access the file, using filewriter

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to check if the file is empty or not, and then write something like "the text is empty" into the document.

But whenever I do get the

> the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

even though I'm closing the file after the write.

What am I missing here?

```
StreamWriter myWriter1 = new StreamWriter(resultpath);
List<string> a = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
List<string> b = File.ReadAllLines(newPath).ToList();

foreach (string s in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    if (!b.Contains(s))
    {
        myWriter1.WriteLine(s);
        myWriter1.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}

string[] resultfile = File.ReadAllLines(resultpath);
if (resultfile == null || resultfile.Length == 0)
{
    myWriter1.WriteLine("Der er ikke nogen udmeldinger idag", true);
}
myWriter1.Close();
```

Comment: Is there a chance that `if (!b.Contains(s))` condition was never met? in this case writer was not closed before reading from the same file.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `myWriter1.Close();` inside the `foreach`loop? and do it right before `string[] resultfile = File.ReadAllLines(resultpath);`?

Comment: Nope, that part is being met and working fine, displays a blank text if everything match.

Comment: Then i get, "cant be written to a closed textwriter"

Comment: wait, so in the first foreach loop, if the string list **b** does not contain one of the strings in **a** you add it to the streamwriter and close the streamwriter. what happens during the next iteration of the loop if we step upon another string not contained in **b**? (the streamwriter would be closed and you'd be trying to write a line to it)

Comment: As expected. You'll need to recreate the writer before `myWriter1.WriteLine("Der er ikke nogen udmeldinger idag", true);`

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner, youre right @Pikoh thanks, post as answer and ill mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You were closing the `StreamWriter` on each line that is in the 2 analized files,but if there is no coincidence, you never close it.

```
using (var myWriter1 = new StreamWriter(resultpath, true))
{
    List<string> a = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
    List<string> b = File.ReadAllLines(newPath).ToList();


    int coincidences=0;
    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);


        if (!b.Contains(s))
        {
            myWriter1.WriteLine(s);
            coincidences++;
        }
    }

    if (coincidences == 0)
    {
         myWriter1.WriteLine("Der er ikke nogen udmeldinger idag", true);
    }

}
```

Also,note that for `IDisposable` objects it's better to enclose it in a `using` clause,as it disposes all the resources when finished.

Answer (score 2):

You can close & dispose file writer after writing to it in the loop and re-create it when you neet to write to the same file again.

Also note it is better to wrap it into `using` statement to ensure it wil be closed and set free unmanaged resources automatically (so you don't need to close it in the loop again and again).

```
List<string> a = File.ReadAllLines(path).ToList();
List<string> b = File.ReadAllLines(newPath).ToList();

using (var myWriter1 = new StreamWriter(resultpath, false))
{
    foreach (string s in a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);

        if (!b.Contains(s))
            myWriter1.WriteLine(s);
    }
}


string[] resultfile = File.ReadAllLines(resultpath);

if (resultfile == null || resultfile.Length == 0)
{
    using (var myWriter1 = new StreamWriter(resultpath, true))
    {
        myWriter1.WriteLine("Der er ikke nogen udmeldinger idag", true);
    }

}
```

Comment: is there any point for doing  `else continue;` in this situation? (just wondering why OP had it and you decided to keep it)

Comment: @Innat3 surely, not ;), thanks, missed that redundancy,